# Apache Tika - Incorrect MIME (content type) detection

Tags: java, apache-tika

I'm trying to detect a file content type passed to a web service into the SOAP envelop.
This file can be indicated in two ways :

- from its url,
- from its contain (base64 compressed data).

At this point, I'm able to translate this file into a stream buffer.
But, all my tries to get its content type failed.
The content type is detected if the file extension is indicated otherwise the content is always detected as "plain/text".

Bellow is my class code :

class MetadataAnalyser {

```
private InputStream _is;

private File _file;

private void initializeAttributes() {

    _is = null;
    _file= null;

}


private void createTemporaryFile(byte[] pData) {

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        _file = File.createTempFile(
                UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-", ""),
                null,
                new File("C:\\Users\\Florent\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\ServiceEdition\\tmp"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(_file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fos.write(pData);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    _file.deleteOnExit();

}

public MetadataAnalyser(byte[] pData) {

    initializeAttributes();
    _is = new ByteArrayInputStream(pData);
    createTemporaryFile(pData);

}

public MetadataAnalyser(InputStream pIs) {

    initializeAttributes();
    _is = pIs;
    _file = null;

}

public MetadataAnalyser(File pFile) {

    initializeAttributes();
    try {
        _file = pFile;
        _is = new FileInputStream(_file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public MetadataAnalyser(String pFile) {

    initializeAttributes();
    try {
        _file = new File(pFile);
        if (_file.exists()) {
            _is = new FileInputStream(_file);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public String getContentType() {

    AutoDetectParser parser = null;
    Metadata metadata = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    String mimeType = null;

    parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    parser.setParsers(new HashMap<MediaType, Parser>());
    metadata = new Metadata();
    if(_file != null) {
        metadata.add(TikaMetadataKeys.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, _file.getName());
    }
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(_file);
        parser.parse(is, new DefaultHandler(), metadata, new ParseContext());
        mimeType = metadata.get(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TikaException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return mimeType;
    }

}
```

}

So, how to detect the MIME type even if the file extension is unknown ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can detect the mime type without extension , you would need to know which system is writing the file and what kind of file is expected to be there and based on that you need to set the MIME type(I guess you are using it in your response).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the content is decoded before being sent to Tika and no, the extension is absolutely not needed, the detection happens via a well understood mime magic process described here: https://tika.apache.org/1.1/detection.html